# I want to capture mouse click event which was clicked outside of the user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a user control in window c# and i am adding that control into another project. I want to capture mouse click event which was clicked outside of the user control. How can i enable this feature in it?

Comment: So capture the event in the another form.

Comment: What a strange requirement.

Comment: can you better explain what you're trying to do? something like that isn't impossible but you probably don't want to catch everything (like clicks on other controls)

Comment: User control contains multiple text boxes. When i entered value in first text box then automatically cursor should move to the next text box after the tab button pressed. But its moving to next control of the project. And i don't have source code of that project. Now, i have added mouse_click and tab button_click code to manually handle the tabbing. I wanted to add code to move focus as per mouse_click outside the boundary of user control.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to assign these,but this should work

```
bool ValidClick = false; 

private void form_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!ValidClick)
        ValidClick = true; 
    method();
}
private void control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidClick = false; 
    method();
}
public void method()
{
    if(ValidClick)
    {
        //Do method
    }
}
```